# Azure data factory: pass where clause as a string to dynamic query with quotes

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Lookup that retrieves a few records from a MS SQL table containing schema, table name and a whole where clause. These values are passed to a copy data (within a ForEach) In the copy data i use a Dynamic query statement like:
@concat('select a.*, current_date as crt_tms from ',item().shm_nam,'.',item().tab_nam,
item().where_clause )

This construction works fine without the where_clause or with a where clause with an integer. But it goes wrong with strings like:
'a where a.CODSYSBRN ='XXX' ;'

it's about the quote (')
How can i pass it through?

I know that the where clause as a fixed string in the dynamic query works when i use double quotes (to escape the single quote):
'a where a.CODSYSBRN =''XXX'' ;'

Point is i need the where clause to be completely dynamic because it differ per table

whatever i try i get this kind of error:
Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "where a"

ps i also tested this, but with the same result:
select a.*, current_date as crt_tms from @{item().shm_nam}.@{item().tab_nam} a @{item().where_clause}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned you are getting whole where clause from the lookup table, the query must have included the column values in where clause for string and integer types separately.

Example lookup table:

[image]

In your copy activity, you can use Concat() function as you were already doing it, to combine static values & parameters.

`@concat('select * from ',item().schma_name,'.',item().table_name,' ',item().where_clause)`

[image]

For debugging purposes, I have added the expression in set variable activity, to see the value of the expression.

**Iteration1:**

[image]

**Iteration2:**

[image]

Comment: it's what i already tried. but still gets refused by the LIBODBCHDB.DLL i think it's the driver that doesn't translate something correctly

Comment: Ok after 10.000 trials i found the issue... you ain't gonna believe this... there was a tab instead of a space in the where clause text....

Comment: Glad that you have found the cause. Thank you for the update.